# QKeyEvent isAutoRepeat not working?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qkeyevent

So, I have an application where if a particular button is kept pressed it plays an audio device, when the button is released it stops the audio device. I use `keyPressEvent` and `KeyReleaseEvent` to implement this which is similar to the code below:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->isAutoRepeat())
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
    else
    {
        if(event->key() == Qt::Key_0)
        {
            qDebug()<<"key_0 pressed"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->isAutoRepeat())
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
    else
    {
        if(event->key() == Qt::Key_0)
        {
            qDebug()<<"key_0 released"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            QWidget::keyReleaseEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

But apparently `isAutoRepeat` function isn't working as I can see continuous print out of `key_0 pressed` and `key_0 released` despite the fact I haven't released the 0 key after I have pressed it. Is my code wrong or something else is wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I think this is happening because the `MainWindow` loses the keyboard focus. How can I actually find out which widget has the focus? I'm actually using some widgets when `Qt::Key_0` pressed, but I thought I set all those possible widgets to `Qt::NoFocus`, I guess it's not working.

I'm trying to know which widget has the focus by doing the following:

```
QWidget * wigdet = QApplication::activeWindow();
qDebug()<<wigdet->accessibleName()<<endl;
```

but it always prints an empty string. How can I make it print the name of the widget which has the keyboard focus?

Comment: Is your class `MainWindow` or `ConsoleMainWindow`? Seems like there is a typo in your question

Comment: Secondly, your code is working for me, just tested it. The doc states : `Note that if the event is a multiple-key compressed event that is partly due to auto-repeat, this function could return either true or false indeterminately`. Are you in this case?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Sorry it was a typo, I changed it. My class is MainWindow.

Comment: What is your OS and your Qt version?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Ubuntu LTS 14.04 and Qt 5.2.1. I don't think the event is a multiple-key compressed event. All it does is increasing the volume of an audio device when pressed and lessening it when released. Is that a mutilple-key compressed event?

Comment: No no it's a simple key event so the problem doesn't come from here. i'm on Windows with Qt5.7 so maybe it is coming from your OS and/or your Qt version... There are some bug reports about this function, see [this one](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-21500) for example

Comment: @IAmInPLS I have added a new edit. Please have a look at it.

Comment: To get the widget having the keyboard focus, it is `QWidget *QApplication::focusWidget()`

Comment: @IAmInPLS I tried to use that too, but it crashes when I tried `qDebug()<<QApplication::focusWidget()->accessibleName()<<endl;`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116052/discussion-between-iaminpls-and-the-naive).

Answer (score 3):

So as I also stumbled over this issue (and grabKeyboard didn't really help), I begun digging in qtbase. It is connected to X11 via xcb, and by default, in case of repeated keys, X11 sends for each repeated key a release-event immediately followed by a key-press-event. So holding down a key results in a sequence of XCB_BUTTON_RELEASE/XCB_BUTTON_PRESS-events beeing sent to the client (try it out with xev or the source at the end of [this page](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/events/)).

Then, qt ([qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbkeyboard.cpp](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbkeyboard.cpp)) tries to figure out from these events whether its an autorepeat case: when a release is received, it uses a lookahead feature to figure if its followed by a press (with timestamps close enough), and if so it assumes autorepeat.

This does not always work, at least not on all platforms. For my case (old and outworn slow laptop (Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2830 @ 2.16GHz × 2) running ubuntu 16.04), it helped to just put a usleep (500) before that check, allowing the press event following the release event to arrive... it's around line 1525 of qxcbkeyboard.cpp:

```
    // look ahead for auto-repeat
    KeyChecker checker(source->xcb_window(), code, time, state);
    usleep(500); // Added, 100 is to small, 200 is ok (for me)
    xcb_generic_event_t *event = connection()->checkEvent(checker);
    if (event) {
    ...
```

Filed this as [QTBUG-57335](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57335).

Nb: The behaviour of X can be changed by using

```
Display *dpy=...;
Bool result;
XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat (dpy, true, &result);
```

Then it wont send this release-press-sequences in case of a hold down key, but using it would require more changes to the autorepeat-detection-logic.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway solved it.

The problem was that I have a widget which is a subclass of QGLWidget which I use to show some augmented reality images from Kinect. This widget takes over the keyboard focus whenever a keyboard button is pressed.

To solve this problem, I needed to call `grabKeyboard` function from the `MainWindow` class (`MainWindow` is a subclass of `QMainWindow`), so `this->grabKeyboard()` is the line I needed to add when `key_0` button is pressed so that `MainWindow` doesn't lose the keyboard focus, and then when the key is released I needed to add the line `this->releaseKeyboard()` to resume normal behaviour, that is, other widgets can have the keyboard focus.